# What's the correct way to use Stubs and Mocks?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, mocking

Here's my example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void NewAction_should_return_IndexAction()
{
    NewViewModel viewModel = new NewViewModel()
    {
        Name = "José Inácio Santos Silva",
        Email = "joseinacio@joseinacio.com",
        Username = "joseinacio"
    };

    //IsUserRegistered is used to validate Username, Username is unique.
    _mockAuthenticationService.Setup(x => x.IsUserRegistered(viewModel.Username )).Returns(false);

    //IsUserRegistered is used to validate Email, Email is unique.
    _mockUsuarioRepository.Setup(x => x.GetUserByEmail(viewModel.Email));
    _mockDbContext.Setup(x => x.SaveChanges());
    _mockUsuarioRepository.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<User>()));

    _userController = new UserController(_mockUsuarioRepository.Object, _mockDbContext.Object, _mockAuthenticationService.Object);

    ActionResult result = _userController.New(viewModel);

    result.AssertActionRedirect().ToAction("Index");

    _mockAuthenticationService.VerifyAll();
    _mockUsuarioRepository.VerifyAll();
    _mockDbContext.VerifyAll();
}
```

I have read some tutorials and they say that we should use **only one mock per test**.

But look at my test, **it use 3 mocks**, to check if my **Action** is working the right way I need to check these 3 mocks, do not agree?

How do I make this test in the correct way?

Comment: I don't feel comfortable posting this as an answer, but my personal opinion is that it's ridiculous to expect only one mock. I would say keep it to as few as you can, and if you have more than (say) five you probably have a code smell, but requiring only one mock strikes me as impractical.

Comment: this may help: http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html

Comment: @Platinum, I disagree. It is impractical to have only one Stub object, obviously. But two mock objects means you are testing two things. It is important to make the distinction between Mocks and Stubs.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that said distinction is *not at all intuitive* from the words themselves. The definitions are completely arbitrary and I can see the definitions being reversed if someone else had coined the words differently. Perhaps you might say that it's important to distinguish between empty mock objects and mock objects with partial implementations? Where I work, the terms are used pretty much interchangeably and it's hard to make a case for prescriptive definitions. The mock vs stub grammar is clearly descriptive.

Comment: You can create a stub using an isolation framework e.g. Moq that is, a Mock object that hasn't been set up. As we've seen the overuse of the work Mock (in discussion and as a C# Type) is causing a lot of confusions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each unit test should test only one thing.

In your unit test you are testing three mock objects. If the mockAuthenticationService fails, this will be reported and the unit test will stop there. Any errors with the other Mock objects are not reported and are effectively hidden.

In this situation you should create three unit tests, and in each one verify only one of the Mock objects. The rest are just used as stubs. *(A stub is exactly the same as a Mock object, except you dont call VerifyAll on it at the end)*

To avoid duplication and wasted effort, you should refactor that unit test so that most of the code is in a separate method. Each of the three unit tests calls this method and then verifies a single Mock.

You also have a test to ensure the correct redirect is called. This should also be in a separate test.

Quite simply:

```
[TestMethod]
public void NewAction_should_checkUserRegistered()
{
    SetupTest();
    _mockAuthenticationService.VerifyAll();
}

[TestMethod]
public void NewAction_should_GetUserByEmail()
{
    SetupTest();
    _mockUsuarioRepository.VerifyAll();
}

[TestMethod]
public void NewAction_should_SaveDBContext()
{
    SetupTest();
    _mockDbContext.VerifyAll();
}

[TestMethod]
public void NewAction_should_return_Redirects_Action()
{
    var novoActionResult = SetupTest();
    novoActionResult.AssertActionRedirect().ToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: I think you're conflating testing one unit of functionality and making multiple assertions in a test. A mock is basically another way of asserting that something happened in the code under test. If a unit of functionality has multiple effects, it's perfectly reasonable to use multiple mocks in a test. What if calling this code with different ViewModels had different effects? With your approach, you'd have a proliferation of tests that would become unreadable. Having too many assertions in a test could also be unreadable. I think the correct answer is to write what best documents your intent.

Comment: @chrispix, I don't think so. If a unit of functionality has multiple effects, then you will want multiple tests - *one test for each effect*. The thing is if you have multiple Mocks in a test -when one Mock fails, that test fails instantly and no further Mocks are tested and reported on. The failure report will then not give you the full picture. To aid debugging as much as possible you need the full picture to hand instantly.

Comment: I have never found a proliferation of well written and well named tests to become unreadable. A well named test - *action_should_doblahblah* - gives a better idea of what is being tested than a *blahblahMock.VerifyAll()*.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: "only one mock per test." is ambiguous. Use as many fakes as you need to isolate the code under test to a "unit" that is testing one condition.
It should be phrased: **Only test one thing per test. If you are checking the state of more than one mock object you are probably testing more than one thing.**

---

Long answer:

There is a lot to answer here to get the unit test written according to the best practices I have come across.

Common terminology from (The Art of Unit Testing), which I hope will come to be common:

**Fake** - an object that isolates the code under test from the rest of the application.
**Stub** - a simple fake object.
**Mock** - a fake object that stores what is passed to it, that you can inspect to verify the test.
Stubs and Mocks are both types of fake.

**"only one mock per test."** is wrong. You use as many fakes as you need to fully isolate the code under test from the rest of the application. If a method takes no parameters, there's nothing to fake. If a method takes a simple data type e.g. `int`, `string`, that doesn't have any complex behaviour, you don't need to fake it. If you have 2 repositories, context, a service object passed in, fake all of them, so no other production methods are being called.

You should have **one condition per test** as @Mongus Pong has said.

Test naming convention: **`MethodUnderTest_Condition_ExpectedBehaviour`** in this case you cannot do that as you have got more than one condition tested.

Test pattern: **Arrange, Act, Assert**. From your test, it seems as that is what you have done, but you have are arranging using private members. You should replace these with variables in each test, since the running order of tests is not always enforced, the state of these variables cannot be guaranteed, making your tests unreliable.

Buy a copy of "The Art of Unit Testing" http://artofunittesting.com/ it will answer a lot of more of your questions and is a great investment; one of the books that I'd grab if the office caught fire.

Comment: True, use as make fakes - but why does this mean use more than one Mock?

Comment: @Mongus I've not said use more than one mock, I've said use as many fakes as possible and said "only one mock per test idiom" is false.

Comment: Logically speaking - by saying the "only one mock per test" is wrong you are saying that "use zero mocks per test or use more than one mock per test" is right.

Comment: @Mongus Your "logically speaking" comment is wrong. Saying "Only use 1" is false, is consistent with saying "Use 0 or 1" is true.

Comment: *boom splatt* <<== My head blowing up! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO mocks and stubs are not that unique defined - every author uses them slightly different.

As I understand *stubs* "mock" behavior or "output" while you use *mocks* for example to check "input" into the mocked object/interface (like the Verify-Methods in MOQ).

If you see it this way then yes I too think you should only use one Mock because you should only test one thing - if you see it more like the stubs to inject testable interfaces then it's impossible to do.

If the VerifyAll is really needed here you indeed use 3 mocks, but I don't think they are nedded.

Comment: From 'XUnit Test Patterns': Stubs provide default values, fake objects provide behavior, mocks validate, dummy values are ignored but needed for compiling.

Comment: @Carsten check my answer for Roy Osherove's definitions of Fakes/Mocks/Stubs. It is the most useful convention and will spread. Your answer is too vague, to answer whether they are needed you need to consider isolation, not whether `VerifyAll()` is needed.

Comment: well I indendet this to point in "Roy"s direction but I held this rather vague because I think there really is not the definition to end it all - but thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use Mock and stubs with Dev Magic Fake, so you can mock the UI and the DB for more information see Dev Magic Fake on codePlex

http://devmagicfake.codeplex.com/

Thanks

M.Radwan